# How to refresh a data-bound collection in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged, inotifycollectionchanged

Im writing a simple wpf application, but Im stuck. I'd like to achieve, that I have a filter class, and If the id has been changed in the filter class by a user input, a list should refresh applying the filter. All the initial bindings are working. The list is displayed properly along with the CompanyId.

the databinding in xaml:

```
<ListBox Height="212" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="211,31,0,0" Name="listBoxProducts" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="267" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=Products}" DisplayMemberPath="CompanyId" />  
<TextBox Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,31,0,0" Name="textBoxCompanyId" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" Text="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=Company.Id}" />
```

The code-behind for the xaml:

```
private TestFactory _testFactory  = new TestFactory();

    private Company _company;
    public Company Company
    {
        get { return _company; }
    }

    private IProductList _products;
    public IProductList Products
    {
        get { return _products; }
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        _company = _testFactory.Company;
        _products = _testFactory.Products;

        InitializeComponent();
        _company.FilterChanged += _testFactory.FilterChanging;
    }
```

The (dummy)factory class:

```
private IProductList _products;
    public IProductList Products 
    {
        get { return _products; }
    }

    private Company _company = new Company();
    public Company Company
    {
        get { return _company; }
    }

    public TestFactory()
    {
        _company = new Company() { Id = 2, Name = "Test Company" };
        GetProducts();
    }

    public void GetProducts()
    {
        var products = new List<Product>();
        products.Add(new Product() { ProductNumber = 1, CompanyId = 1, Name = "test product 1" });
        products.Add(new Product() { ProductNumber = 2, CompanyId = 1, Name = "test product 2" });
        products.Add(new Product() { ProductNumber = 3, CompanyId = 2, Name = "test product 3" });

        if (Company.Id != 2)
        {
            products = products.Where(p => p.CompanyId == Company.Id).ToList();
        }

        _products = new ProductList(products);
    }

    public void FilterChanging(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetProducts();
    }
```

The ProductList interface:

```
public interface IProductList : IList<Product>, INotifyCollectionChanged {}
```

The productlist class:

```
public class ProductList : IProductList
{
    private readonly IList<Product> _products;

    public ProductList() { }

    public ProductList(IList<Product> products)
    {
        _products = products;
    }


    public IEnumerator<Product> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _products.GetEnumerator();
    }


    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }


    public void Add(Product item)
    {
        _products.Add(item);
        notifyCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item));
    }


    public void Clear()
    {
        _products.Clear();
        notifyCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }


    public bool Contains(Product item)
    {
        return _products.Contains(item);
    }


    public void CopyTo(Product[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _products.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }


    public bool Remove(Product item)
    {
        var removed = _products.Remove(item);

        if (removed)
        {
            notifyCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item));
        }
        return removed;
    }


    public int Count
    {
        get { return _products.Count; }
    }


    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return _products.IsReadOnly; }
    }


    public int IndexOf(Product item)
    {
        return _products.IndexOf(item);
    }


    public void Insert(int index, Product item)
    {
        _products.Insert(index, item);
        notifyCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }


    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        _products.RemoveAt(index);
        notifyCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }


    public Product this[int index]
    {
        get { return _products[index]; }
        set
        {
            _products[index] = value;
            notifyCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, _products[index]));
        }
    }


    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    private void notifyCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
        {
            CollectionChanged(this, args);
        }
    }
}
```

The Company class (filter class):

```
public class Company : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set 
        {
            if (_id == value)
                return;

            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Id");

            OnFilterChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name == value)
                return;

            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event EventHandler FilterChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged == null)
            return;

        var eventArgs = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name);
        PropertyChanged(this, eventArgs);
    }

    private void OnFilterChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FilterChanged == null)
            return;

        FilterChanged(this, e);
    }
}
```

The list is refreshed in factory, but there is no change in the view. I probably do something wrong, maybe my whole approach is not best. Maybe I have to use ObservableCollection type with valueconverter? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an `ObservableCollection<Product>` instead of creating your own list based on `IList`

The purpose of an `ObservableCollection` is to track changes to the collection, and it will automatically update the UI when the collection changes.

Comment: If I'd ,like to implement the ObservableCollection<Product>, do I need a ValueConverter or not?

Comment: Do I still need a function subscribing to an event to notify the view, there is some change happened in the collection or not?


btw I found a solution to my problem, but I'm still not sure, wheather its the right or not.
If I modify the GetProducts() like this its working:

    ...if (_products != null)
            {
                _products.Clear();
                products.Where(product => product.CompanyId == _company.Id).ToList().ForEach(product => _products.Add(product));
            }
            else 
            {
                _products = products;
            }
what do you think?

Comment: @JahManCan No you don't - `ObservableCollections` will automatically tell the View if it's collection has been modified. Simply bind directly to the collection: `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyObservableCollection}" ... />`

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider using ICollectionView for this use-case.

Refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140930/wpf-icollectionview-filtering).

Comment: I rather avoid this approach, there must be a more simple way to make this work.